# Http request without verifying SSL Certificate

Tags: php, laravel, http

I'm trying to fetch the data from this API and I was getting a SSL Certificate error and found this solution, but the I don't know if this is the best solution for handling this, is there a better way instead of using withoutVerifying() in this case? My code:

```
Route::get('/test', function () {
    
    $response = Http::withoutVerifying()->get('https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/bitcoin');

    return $response;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Then use SSL on your server. That's the best way.